# DOJO/Ajax: Dynamic Loading of Content & DOJO Upgrade

Tags: ajax, dojo

In my application I am expected to show come configurations on UI. Currently appication makes a DOJO call and displays all the configs in UI. But, we are facing time out issues in case of huge configs say 5000 or more, which subsequently takes more time to load the page and application gets timed out since the default time for DOJO is around 3mins.

Solution: We are planning to make subsequent AJAX calls and display 50 rows of configurations at a time. This would mean, that after displaying 50 rows of configs, application will make another AJAX call until all the configs are loaded on the page. This will ensure that DOJO call is not getting timed out. We are planning to move forward with DOJO.xhrGet or DOJO.xhrPost which is a part of request package in DOJO 1.8.

Now, the issue here is that my application is configured with very old version of DOJO. Since, we want to include new request methods which are introduced in DOJO 1.8, what changes will be required here?

We have tried by including the request methods in DOJO.JS but we can see that it impacts other application aspects. Can you please let me know the steps required to include this new package in DOJO.JS?? For reference, please find a snippet of my DOJO.JS.

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thanks!!! :)

/*
    Copyright (c) 2004-2006, The Dojo Foundation
    All Rights Reserved.

```
Licensed under the Academic Free License version 2.1 or above OR the
modified BSD license. For more information on Dojo licensing, see:

    http://dojotoolkit.org/community/licensing.shtml
```

*/

/*
    This is a compiled version of Dojo, built for deployment and not for
    development. To get an editable version, please visit:

```
    http://dojotoolkit.org

for documentation and information on getting the source.
```

*/

```
if (typeof dojo == "undefined") {
    var dj_global = this;
    function dj_undef(_1, _2) {
        if (_2 == null) {
            _2 = dj_global;
        }
        return (typeof _2[_1] == "undefined");
    }
    if (dj_undef("djConfig")) {
        var djConfig = {};
    }
    if (dj_undef("dojo")) {
        var dojo = {};
    }
    dojo.version = {major:0,minor:3,patch:1,flag:"",revision:Number("$Rev: 4342 $".match(/[0-9]+/)[0]),toString:function() {
        with (dojo.version) {
            return major + "." + minor + "." + patch + flag + " (" + revision + ")";
        }
    }};
    dojo.evalProp = function(_3, _4, _5) {
        return (_4 && !dj_undef(_3, _4) ? _4[_3] : (_5 ? (_4[_3] = {}) : undefined));
    };
    dojo.parseObjPath = function(_6, _7, _8) {
        var _9 = (_7 != null ? _7 : dj_global);
        var _a = _6.split(".");
        var _b = _a.pop();
        for (var i = 0,l = _a.length; i < l && _9; i++) {
            _9 = dojo.evalProp(_a[i], _9, _8);
        }
        return {obj:_9,prop:_b};
    };
    dojo.evalObjPath = function(_d, _e) {
        if (typeof _d != "string") {
            return dj_global;
        }
        if (_d.indexOf(".") == -1) {
            return dojo.evalProp(_d, dj_global, _e);
        }
        var _f = dojo.parseObjPath(_d, dj_global, _e);
        if (_f) {
            return dojo.evalProp(_f.prop, _f.obj, _e);
        }
        return null;
    };
    dojo.errorToString = function(_10) {
        if (!dj_undef("message", _10)) {
            return _10.message;
        } else {
            if (!dj_undef("description", _10)) {
                return _10.description;
            } else {
                return _10;
            }
        }
    };
    dojo.raise = function(_11, _12) {
        if (_12) {
            _11 = _11 + ": " + dojo.errorToString(_12);
        }
        try {
            dojo.hostenv.println("FATAL: " + _11);
        }
        catch(e) {
        }
        throw Error(_11);
    };
    dojo.debug = function() {
    };
    dojo.debugShallow = function(obj) {
    };
    dojo.profile = {start:function() {
    },end:function() {
    },stop:function() {
    },dump:function() {
    }};
    function dj_eval(_14) {
        return dj_global.eval ? dj_global.eval(_14) : eval(_14);
    }
    dojo.unimplemented = function(_15, _16) {
        var _17 = "'" + _15 + "' not implemented";
        if (_16 != null) {
            _17 += " " + _16;
        }
        dojo.raise(_17);
    };
    dojo.deprecated = function(_18, _19, _1a) {
        var _1b = "DEPRECATED: " + _18;
        if (_19) {
            _1b += " " + _19;
        }
        if (_1a) {
            _1b += " -- will be removed in version: " + _1a;
        }
        dojo.debug(_1b);
    };
    dojo.inherits = function(_1c, _1d) {
        if (typeof _1d != "function") {
            dojo.raise("dojo.inherits: superclass argument [" + _1d + "] must be a function (subclass: [" + _1c + "']");
        }
        _1c.prototype = new _1d();
        _1c.prototype.constructor = _1c;
        _1c.superclass = _1d.prototype;
        _1c["super"] = _1d.prototype;
    };
    dojo.render = (function() {
        function vscaffold(_1e, _1f) {
            var tmp = {capable:false,support:{builtin:false,plugin:false},prefixes:_1e};
            for (var _21 in _1f) {
                tmp[_21] = false;
            }
            return tmp;
        }
        return {name:"",ver:dojo.version,os:{win:false,linux:false,osx:false},html:vscaffold(["html"], ["ie","opera","khtml","safari","moz"]),svg:vscaffold(["svg"], ["corel","adobe","batik"]),vml:vscaffold(["vml"], ["ie"]),swf:vscaffold(["Swf","Flash","Mm"], ["mm"]),swt:vscaffold(["Swt"], ["ibm"])};
    })();
    dojo.hostenv = (function() {
        var _22 = {isDebug:false,allowQueryConfig:false,baseScriptUri:"",baseRelativePath:"",libraryScriptUri:"",iePreventClobber:false,ieClobberMinimal:true,preventBackButtonFix:true,searchIds:[],parseWidgets:true};
        if (typeof djConfig == "undefined") {
            djConfig = _22;
        } else {
            for (var _23 in _22) {
                if (typeof djConfig[_23] == "undefined") {
                    djConfig[_23] = _22[_23];
                }
            }
        }
        return {name_:"(unset)",version_:"(unset)",getName:function() {
            return this.name_;
        },getVersion:function() {
            return this.version_;
        },getText:function(uri) {
            dojo.unimplemented("getText", "uri=" + uri);
        }};
    })();
    dojo.hostenv.getBaseScriptUri = function() {
        if (djConfig.baseScriptUri.length) {
            return djConfig.baseScriptUri;
        }
        var uri = new String(djConfig.libraryScriptUri || djConfig.baseRelativePath);
        if (!uri) {
            dojo.raise("Nothing returned by getLibraryScriptUri(): " + uri);
        }
        var _26 = uri.lastIndexOf("/");
        djConfig.baseScriptUri = djConfig.baseRelativePath;
        return djConfig.baseScriptUri;
    };
    (function() {
        var _27 = {pkgFileName:"__package__",loading_modules_:{},loaded_modules_:{},addedToLoadingCount:[],removedFromLoadingCount:[],inFlightCount:0,modulePrefixes_:{dojo:{name:"dojo",value:"src"}},setModulePrefix:function(_28, _29) {
            this.modulePrefixes_[_28] = {name:_28,value:_29};
        },getModulePrefix:function(_2a) {
            var mp = this.modulePrefixes_;
            if ((mp[_2a]) && (mp[_2a]["name"])) {
                return mp[_2a].value;
            }
            return _2a;
        },getTextStack:[],loadUriStack:[],loadedUris:[],post_load_:false,modulesLoadedListeners:[],unloadListeners:[],loadNotifying:false};
        for (var _2c in _27) {
            dojo.hostenv[_2c] = _27[_2c];
        }
    })();
```

Comment: dojo.xhrGet and dojo.xhrPost are present in Dojo since at least Dojo v1.3.  You should be able to use these without the patching you're considering...

Comment: Thanks for your response Nick.. In my dojo.js, I cannot find any definition of dojo.xhrGet and dojo.xhrPost methods.